# iOS Convert NSString to NSDate alway nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I'm trying to convert string to `NSdate`. The string date is "**12/27/2014 07:42:00 AM +0000**"

Here is my code:

```
NSDate *date =[[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
date = [ dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

The date value is always nil. Any of you knows what canI be doing wrong?

I'll really appreaciate your help.

Comment: The [[NSDate alloc] init] is totally pointless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z";
```

as `HH` is 24-hour and conflicts `a`. `Z` stands for the timezone offset.

have a look on the specifiers: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

---

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z";
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
// see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html


NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    NSString *str =@"12/27/2014 07:42:00 AM +0000";        
    NSDateFormatter *sdateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    sdateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [sdateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z'"];

    NSDate *sdate = [sdateFormatter dateFromString:str];
    NSLog(@"%@",[sdateFormatter stringFromDate:sdate]);
```